# Mapping jsonobject to Class with multiple key value pair

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object like this  , i want to map it to a class object Stock as given below .

Input Object

```
        var inputJson = [{
            "HS": "   ",
            "__EMPTY": 1,
            "__EMPTY_1": "    Pcs."
        },
        {
            "HS": " RAS222PCAIBA",
            "__EMPTY": 1,
            "__EMPTY_1": "    Pcs."
        },
        {
            "HS": "     SRK20CSS-S6/A1.6T",
            "__EMPTY": -4,
            "__EMPTY_1": "    Pcs."
        }]
```

Class

```
        class Stocks {
          model;
          quantity;
          type;
          constructor(data) {
            Object.assign(this, data);
          }
        }
```

i am trying to get the refined class object in an array like this

```
    var completeStock = [] ; 
       $.each(inputJson, function( index, value ) {
         completeStock.push(new Stocks(value));
      });
```

But this is adding the object keys rather than mapping the first object key to model , second key to Quantity and ther third key to type.  How can i achieve this .

Answer (score 0):

You can just extract out the values from object and assign them to the class properties like below

```
var completeStock = [];
$.each(inputJson, function(index, value) {
  const {HS: model, __EMPTY: quantity, __EMPTY_1: type} = value;
  completeStock.push(new Stocks({ model, quantity, type }));
});
console.log(completeStock)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clearly define the mappings in the constructor.
Your constructor will only work with the same property names of the `inputJson`.

Modify your constructor like this, Now we have defined clear mappings in the constructor.

```
 class Stock {
          model;
          quantity;
          type;
          constructor(data) {
                         this.model = data.HS;
                            this.quantity = data.__EMPTY;
                            this.type = data.__EMPTY_1
          }
        }
```

Now you will be able to map them correctly.